# How to remove mouseleave event if it exits?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events

After click on the box, take your mouse out of the browser window or that running screen and see the alert. Why this is happening, how can I terminate the mouseleave event after clicked outside the box?

```js
['pointerup', 'mouseleave', 'touchend'].forEach(function(item) {
  document.body.addEventListener(item, myy);
});

function myy(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('container')) {

  console.log('clicked');

  } else {
    alert('yy');
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  background: tomato;
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>
    After click on the box, take your mouse out of the browser window or that running screen and see the alert.
  </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: This is because you have `mouseleave` in the array. Remove that and it won't alert when you move mouse out of running screen. To remove conditionally, you can use `removeEventListener`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Comment: its giving the same output when I remove it from the array and just do it simply